# Can't install Windows 7 through VMware Fusion,  missing CD/DVD drivers

Tags: windows-7, macos, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to install Windows 7 32 Bit. There is no "easy install" for the VMware Fusion 4 setup as shown in this vide. http://www.vmwarefusionlearningcenter.com/intro-to-fusion.html#3

And when I try to install it through VMware it starts up Windows 7 setup, where I press "install now" and it shows a window saying

> Select the driver to be installed

and a popup comes up saying

> A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD or USB flash drive, please insert it now.

Why would this come in in the installation, and what I can do about it?

Comment: @slhck Post was updated

Answer (score 1):

This is really silly, it turned out I had downloaded an incomplete copy of windows, I redownloaded it and it works now.

Comment: I encountered this same issue. Glad you pointed it out, otherwise I would have been searching around forever!